# How to flip a complex box2d fixture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics

I have a complex CCSprite in which I am using Physics Editor software to create the fixtures for it. The b2Body which contains the CCSprite goes back and forth horizontally on the ipad screen. The problem I am facing is that the fixture doesnt actually get flipped along the x-axis. What is the best way to flip a fixture horizontally?

My approach,

I had two sets of fixtures in two separate plists. One for when the sprite is moving to the right and the other for when the sprite is moving to the left.

Since there is no replaceFixture function for a b2Body object, I am destroying the appropriate fixture and adding this fixture again.

Is this the right approach or is there any other approach that is effective?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of destroying and re-creating the fixtures, you could have both fixtures present all the time, and just change their collision filter settings, so that when moving left one of the fixtures has collision disabled, and switch that around when moving right.

(This would make the body twice as heavy so you might want to halve the density of the fixtures to keep the same mass.)